# Why the wt-sky-root div appears in my html when I don't write it in fi

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I have found a strange div with class "wt-sky-root". What is it and how to delete it? In code, I don't see any such divs or etc. But when I use developer console in Chrome, I see such div in elements. That's my code. Also, the javascript file is empty.

Screen of Chorme:
[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Diary</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100italic,200,200italic,300,300italic,regular,italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic,900,900italic" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="day">Monday</h1>
  <h2 class="subject">Landing</h2>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 100px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  background-color: #a4508b;
  background-image: linear-gradient(326deg, #a4508b 0%, #5f0a87 74%);
  color: white;
}


h1 {
  font-size: 90px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: `wt-sky-root` is a widget. which cms or framework are you using?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov as I understand, it was a file from a live server, because when I launched just HTML file in a browser, that div was gone. So, I make a decision, to make a wrapper with height and width of "body" and make HTML code there for сlear off postition bugs of items.

Comment: I am getting this div because of the vimbox extension

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable browser extensions, it was helpful for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).